# How can i change the color of my text when it is posted? [HTML]

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, textcolor

i'm working with my simple coding tutorial for our software engineering class project. 
How can i change the color of the text of the reserve word in programming for example is I entered some text in the `<textarea>` like this.

```
public class Dog{


}
```

because public and class is a reserve word in java, the plain black color from the textarea will be changed to blue and red when it is posted.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use regular expressions to find such keywords

Comment: you want to code this from scratch? just use `markdown` plugin instead

Comment: prism.js, highlightjs, codemirror, etc, but you can't do that in a textarea, only a contenteditable element